# Android - no free space

Tags: android, fileoutputstream, internal-storage

```
try {           
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
    bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I write this code to save bitmap and it works fine, please tell me if there not be free space in internal storage, what would happen: stop application? or just would ignore saving without any stoppings and exceptions? or just would tell that no free space? or smth else?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws an exception like this: `java.io.IOException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)`

Comment: thank you, in that case would application stop working or only would tell (No space left on device)?

Comment: You need to catch the `IOException` and handle it properly, for example by communicating to the user that an error has occurred or by deleting other files your app has created and no longer needs to free space and trying again.